# grpc async request without waiting for result

Tags: netty, grpc, grpc-java

I have two netty java grpc servers: `ServerA` and `ServerB`.

one of my request flows looks like this:

1. client makes rpc to `ServerA`.
2. `ServerA` makes async rpc to `ServerB`.
3. without waiting for the result of the async rpc, the request to `ServerA` completes. i.e. the logic simply makes the async rpc and is then done.

what would happen here? does the thread on `ServerA` that is processing the client request wait to exit before the thread making the async rpc completes? Is there a chance the async request just never goes through? Or perhaps it errors out because the client is gone?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC threading model is different from Servlet-like threading model where every request is bound to a Thread for that request's lifetime.

gRPC doesn't take into account the interactions from the example, and would "just work" without any thread waiting. With one caveat. `io.grpc.Context` is used to auto-propagate deadlines and cancellations. With it gRPC can notice that one RPC is related to the other, and cancel the async RPC when the initial RPC completes. It's possible to use `Context.fork()` to avoid that.